Где можно найти в райдере call stack?
Никак не могу разобраться, где он находится,а точнее - понять, за что какое из показанных ниже окон отвечает,  заранее извиняюсь за может очень глупый вопрос

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Examining_Suspended_Program.html#what-is-a-frame
